# JavaScript выполнение оператора return после перебора массива

Tags: javascript, return

Суть задачи: задается массив из имен. Необходимо вернуть в итого массив с именами длина которых равна 4 знакам.

```
function friend(friends){
  var arrFriends = friends;
  for (var s=0;s<arrFriends.length;s++){
    if (arrFriends[s].length =4){
      return arrFriends[s];
    }
  }
}
console.log(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"]));
```

Мой код в принципе работает, но одно но мой оператор return завершает выполнение текущей функции, а я бы хотел чтобы он перебрал весь массив а после уже вернул ответ.

Comment: В условии складывайте значение в отдельную переменную вне цикла и после окончания цикла делайте `return`

Comment: return **всегда** завершает выполнение функции. Поэтому если нужно возвращать результат после перебора массива, то и нужно ставить return после перебора массива, а не в цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"].filter(i => i.length == 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно

```
 function friend(friends){
  var retFriends = [];
  for (var s=0;s<friends.length;s++){
    if (friends[s].length === 4){
      retFriends.push(friends[s]);
    }
  }
  return retFriends;
}
console.log(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"]));
```

1. не было необходимости объявлять передаваемый массив внутри функции второй раз

2. `if (arrFriends[s].length =4){` одно = это присваивание, а нужно было сравнение, то есть == (нестрогое сравнение) или === (строгое сравнение)

Answer (score -1):

```
function friend(friends){
  suitable_values = []
  for (var s=0; s < friends.length; s++){
    if (friends[s].length == 4){
      suitable_values.push(friends[s])
    }
  }
  return suitable_values
}
console.log(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark"]))
```